# SQL select rows with different values in two column

Tags: sql, sqlite, multiple-columns

I have database with 4-5 tables.
I'm collecting data like this

```
N | Nom_  | Soni_  | Savdo  | Foyda  | Val(Currency)
1 | Apple |    5kg | 5000   |   500  | UZS
2 | Banana|    4kg | 7000   |   800  | UZS
3 | Peach |    2kg | 2      |   0.2  | USD
```

And I want to separate **Currency** column two column like below

```
N | Nom_  | Soni_  | Savdo  | Foyda  | Val1  |  Val2
1 | Apple |    5kg | 5000   |   500  | UZS   |
2 | Banana|    4kg | 7000   |   800  | UZS   |
3 | Peach |    2kg | 2      |   0.2  |       |   USD
```

Here is my SQL code.

```
select  s.nom_ , sum(o.soni_) as soni_ ,
   sum(o.soni_*(select narx_ from toper where id_=o.id_ )) as savdo_, 
   sum((o.soni_*o.narx_-o.soni_* (select narx_ from toper where id_=o.id_op ))) as foyda_,
   (select nom_ from tsinf where id_=o.id_v) as val_ 
      from toper o left join tsf f on o.id_sf=f.id_  
      left join tsinf s on o.id_s=s.id_  
where (f.date_>=date('2020-01-01')) and (f.date_<=date('2020-04-04')) 
and f.oper_=-1  group by id_s, id_v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the subquery to the `FROM` clause (using `LEFT JOIN`).  Then the split is just two `CASE` expressions:

```
select s.nom_ , sum(o.soni_) as soni_,
       sum(o.soni_*(select narx_ from toper where id_=o.id_ )) as savdo_, 
       sum((o.soni_*o.narx_-o.soni_* (select narx_ from toper where id_=o.id_op ))) as foyda_,
        (case when sv.nom_1 = 'UZS' then sv.nom_1 end) as uzs,
        (case when sv.nom_1 = 'USD' then sv.nom_1 end) as usd
from toper o left join
     tsf f
     on o.id_sf = f.id_  left join
     tsinf s
     on o.id_s = s.id_ left join
     tsinf sv
     on sv.id_ = o.id_v
where f.date_ >= date('2020-01-01') and
      f.date_ <= date('2020-04-04') and 
      f.oper_ = -1 
group by id_s, id_v ;
```

I would also recommend removing the subqueries to `toper`, but that would be another question.

Comment: Thanks [Gordon-Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)  it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Put your query inside a `CTE` and then use a `CASE` expression to select the 2 columns:

```
with cte as (
  select s.nom_ , sum(o.soni_) as soni_ ,
    sum(o.soni_*(select narx_ from toper where id_=o.id_ )) as savdo_, 
    sum((o.soni_*o.narx_-o.soni_* (select narx_ from toper where id_=o.id_op ))) as foyda_,
    (select nom_ from tsinf where id_=o.id_v) as val_ 
  from toper o left join tsf f on o.id_sf=f.id_  
  left join tsinf s on o.id_s=s.id_  
  where (f.date_>=date('2020-01-01')) and (f.date_<=date('2020-04-04')) 
  and f.oper_=-1  
  group by id_s, id_v
)
select nom_, soni, savdo, foyda_, 
  case when val_ = 'UZS' then val_ end as Val1,
  case when val_ = 'USD' then val_ end as Val2 
from cte
```

But you should know that the condition:

```
where (f.date_>=date('2020-01-01')) and (f.date_<=date('2020-04-04'))
```

changes your `left` join to `tsf` to an `inner` join. If the results are what you expect then fine. If not move these conditions to the `ON` clause.
Also instead of all the `select` statements that you use in the select list, you could use `joins` if the relationships are 1:1.
Try this:

```
select  
  s.nom_, 
  sum(o.soni_) as soni_,
  sum(o.soni_* o2.narx_) as savdo_, 
  sum((o.soni_*o.narx_-o.soni_* o3.narx_) as foyda_,
  case when s2.nom_ = 'UZS' then s2.nom_ end as Val1,
  case when s2.nom_ = 'USD' then s2.nom_ end as Val2 
from toper o 
left join toper o2 on o2.id_=o.id_
left join toper o3 on o3.id_=o.id_op
left join tsf f on o.id_sf=f.id_  
left join tsinf s on o.id_s=s.id_ 
left join tsinf s2 on o.id_v=s2.id_  
where (f.date_>=date('2020-01-01')) and (f.date_<=date('2020-04-04')) and f.oper_=-1  
group by id_s, id_v
```

Comment: Thank you [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) for attention and spending time. Your version was also perfect.

Comment: @HayrullaMelibayev don't use subqueries in the select list. This is where you do joins between the tables and this is the reason why there are joins in sql. When you mix subqueries and joins you make your code difficult to maintain.